# Read add-in Excel output from Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, add-in, xlsread

I have written an Excel file in which I compute some values using the Refprop add-in ([link to refprop](http://www.nist.gov)). Then there is a Matlab script that writes the input values in this .xlsx file through `xlswrite`.

The problem is that the Refprop add-in seems to be disable and output values are not updated.

Can I activate the Excel's add-in after I've used `xlswrite` in order to read the output from Matlab?

I'm using Matlab2014a and Excel2013 on Windows 8.1 (64bit).

Thank you

Comment: I highly doubt that you can because the add-in probably requires the file to be open in Excel to perform any calculations. This sounds like a use case for the Matlab excel add-in, spreadsheetlink, if you have budget for it? It will aloow you to interact with Excel while the file is open in Excel and thus the Refprop add-in will be loaded and functioning

Comment: So you are suggesting to use Matlab script as Excel add-in? What do you mean for "budget"?

Comment: I mean use this: http://www.mathworks.com/products/excellink/ and that it is not free